# History behind Exact Sequences.

Tags: math-history, homological-algebra, motivation, abstract-algebra

I am very much interested in listening to the history behind the exact sequence. We know that the exact sequence is sequence of objects with morphisms such that image of one morphism equals to the kernel of the next one.

But how did the whole idea start ? .

What is the motivation behind considering the image and kernel equality and linking groups ? .

How did the exact sequences come into play ?.

I want to hear some on some of the above things.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not an answer. But here is a link you might find useful: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0245/. Check out the pdf file.

Comment: While the concept of an exact sequence is purely algebraic, I dare guess that the origin is from topology/analysis/differential equations. At least yours truly first encountered the word "exact" during an elementary course on differential equations. See [this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) I'm no historian, so my impression may be false, and only reflects the order in which I was exposed to various parts of math.

Comment: Weibel has some remarks about the history of exact sequences in Chapter 1 of _An introduction to homological algebra_.

Comment: Sir, Can you tell any motivation behind the kernel image equality ?. Why one needs to consider that ? @ZhenLin

Comment: IMHO the first time a keen student encounters the kernel image equality is with theorems like (in $\mathbf{R}^3$) *The curl of a vector field vanishes, iff the vector field is the gradient of a function* and *the divergence of a vector field vanishes, iff the vector field is the curl of another*. Of course, these are just reinterpretations of the vanishing of certain de Rham cohomology groups, but they do show up many times, when learning vector analysis. See Poincaré Lemma (in the link of my previous comment).

Answer (score 8):

In *A History of Algebraic and Differential Topology*, Chapter 5, §5,
Dieudonné says that Hurewicz introduced exact sequences in 1941.

On the other hand, Weibel in his [History of Homological Algebra](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0245/survey.pdf) [1] says that
Kelley and Pitcher coined the term “exact sequence” in 1947 [2].

[1] History of Homological Algebra, in *History of topology* (edited by I. M. James), 1999.

[2] Exact homomorphism sequences in homology theory, *Annals
of Math.* 48 (1947), 682–709.

Comment: +1: But this answer is not complete one. I asked the motivation too ( regarding the kernel image equality , and why one needs to consider that ? ) . But any way thank you.

Comment: @Iyengar, I don't know about motivation but Dieudonné says that equality was "Hurewicz's essential remark". Read that section in Amazon or Google Books.

Comment: I found the reference to Weibel's survey in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153958/history-of-modern-mathematics-available-on-the-internet.

Comment: There is an anecdote about the origin of "exact sequence" at this MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48491/why-are-differential-forms-called-closed-and-exact/48493#48493

Comment: @lhf : Thank you sir.

Comment: @Raeder : Thank you sir for your link...

Answer (score 3):

The following is an extract of S. Krantz's wonderful *Mathematical Apocrypha Redux* which should answer your question:

> It seems that the *concept* of exact sequence originates with Hurewicz (*Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society* 47(1941),562). But he did not use the term. In fact the terminology made its debut in a paper of John L. Kelley and Everett Pitcher (*Annals of Mathematics* 47(1947), 682-709). Although they may have the first citation in print, they humbly attribute the terminology to Eilenberg and Steenrod, who cooked up the language for use in their classic text *Foundations of Algebraic Topology*. Evidently, in their original draft for that book, they left a blank space for every occurrence of the idea. They were seeking just the right language, and were waiting for inspiration to hit. Eilenberg used the term "exact sequence" in a course he taught at the University of Michigan in 1946. He and Steenrod adopted it for their book, which was published in 1952. In the abstracts of talks that Kelley and Pitcher submitted in 1945 and 1946, they alluded to the idea of exact sequence, but they used the language "natural homomorphism sequence." We can be grateful that, for their published work, they adopted the more elegant language "exact sequence." That is the 
>   argot that lives on today.