# History of Modern Mathematics Available on the Internet

Tags: reference-request, math-history, online-resources

I have been meaning to ask this question for some time, and have been spurred to do so by Georges Elencwajg's fantastic answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147561/sheaves-and-complex-analysis/147676#147676) question and the link contained therein.

In my free time I enjoy reading historical accounts of "recent" mathematics (where, to me, recent means within the last 100 years). A few favorites of mine being Alexander Soifer's [The Mathematical Coloring Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387746404), Allyn Jackson's two part mini-biography of Alexander Grothendieck ([Part I](http://www.ams.org/notices/200409/fea-grothendieck-part1.pdf) and [Part II](http://www.ams.org/notices/200410/fea-grothendieck-part2.pdf)) and Charles Weibel's [History of Homological Algebra](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0245/survey.pdf).

My question is then:

> What freely available resources (i.e. papers, theses, articles) are there concerning the history of "recent" mathematics on the internet?

I would like to treat this question in a manner similar to my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144165/free-graph-theory-resources) about graph theory resources, namely as a list of links to the relevant materials along with a short description. Perhaps one person (I would do this if necessary) could collect all the suggestions and links into one answer which could be used a repository for such materials.

Any suggestions I receive in the comments will listed below.

Suggestions in the Comments:

- [Gregory H. Moore, The emergence of open sets, closed sets, and limit points in analysis and topology]

  [http://mcs.cankaya.edu.tr/~kenan/Moore2008.pdf](http://mcs.cankaya.edu.tr/%7Ekenan/Moore2008.pdf)

Comment: Mactutor: http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Chronology/index.html

Comment: I can facilitate you the 3 volumes of History of Number Theory.

Comment: The beautiful article by Gregory H. Moore, *The emergence of open sets, closed sets, and limit points in analysis and topology* is linked to [in this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/70445/5363).

Comment: @petertamaroff I would very much appreciate that. How would we go about it?

Comment: @Holdsworth88 Give me an e-mail address, and I'll attach the files.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Could you send the documents to this address: automorphism88@googlemail.com? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Babois's  thesis](http://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/43/02/04/PDF/these.pdf)  on the birth of the cohomology of groups .

[Beaulieu](http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/~pavlov/bourbaki.pdf)  on Bourbaki

[Brechenmacher](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/63/73/78/PDF/C._Math._ENS._Brechenmacher06.pdf)  on the history of  matrices

[Demazure's eulogy](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Gazette/2009/120/smf_gazette_120_5-8.pdf)       of Henri Cartan
[Serre's eulogy](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Gazette/2009/121/smf_gazette_121_65-70.pdf)   of Henri Cartan

[Dolgachev](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/cremona.pdf) on Cremona and algebraic cubic surfaces

[The Hirzebruch-Atiyah](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/ah.pdf) correspondence on $K$-theory

[Krömer's thesis](http://poincare.univ-nancy2.fr/digitalAssets/20585_these-kroemer.pdf) on the beginnings of category theory

[Raynaud](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/Raynaud.pdf) on Grothendieck and schemes.

[Rubin](http://math.uci.edu/~krubin/lectures/psbreakfast.pdf) on the solving of Fermat's last theorem.

[Schneps's review](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/corr.pdf) of the book *The Grothendieck-Serre Correspondence*

Comment: Interesting! I will definitely have a look some of those.

Answer (score 3):

Things I have found so far:

- [Who is Alexander Gorthendieck](http://www.ams.org/notices/200808/tx080800930p.pdf) by Winfried Scharlau
- [Mathematics at Göttingen under the Nazis](http://www.ams.org/notices/199510/maclane.pdf) by Saunders Mac Lane
- [History of Knot Theory](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703096v1.pdf) by Józef H. Przytycki
- [The Life and Works of Raoul Bott](http://www.math.harvard.edu/history/bott/bottbio/0201027-1.pdf) by Loring W. Tu